# Add actual OPTION values to the LIs generated by CHOSEN

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-chosen

I am using `CHOSEN 1.3.0` to generate the multi-select list dropdown in combination with `JQuery SORTABLE`.

Users can select multiple elements to select list as well as, most importantly, can sort those elements. (I have combined `JQuery SORTABLE` and `JQuery CHOSEN`)

This is the code that I can get those SORTED elements of that CHOSEN dropdown.

```
$('.chosen-choices').sortable({
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        var data = "";
        $(".chosen-choices li").each(function(i, el){
            var p = $(el).text().toLowerCase().replace(" ", "_");
            data += p + "=" + $(el).index() + ",";
        });
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

But I can only get index of those sorted elements in order, NOT the actuall `value` of those options.

As you know `CHOSEN` generates that LIs like so.

```
<ul class="chosen-choices ui-sortable">
    <li class="search-choice ui-sortable-handle">
        <span>Karachi</span>
        <a class="search-choice-close" data-option-array-index="0"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

To be precise my question. If I have `<option value="19">Karachi</option>` in my actual Select list, how do I ask CHOSEN to generated

```
<li class="search-choice ui-sortable-handle" value="19">
    <span>Karachi</span>
    <a class="search-choice-close" data-option-array-index="0"></a>
</li>
```

for me having `value` tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for the line in your Chosen.JS

`return c=a("<li />",{"class":"search-choice"})`

And modify to this

`return c=a("<li />",{"class":"search-choice", "value":b.value})`